# Setup 3 monitors linux

Tags: linux, graphics-card, multiple-monitors

Well, I want to setup 3 monitors, 2 with my Nnvidia GTX 570, and 1 with the OnBoard Intel. I'm using archlinux. When I execute lspci, the 2 graphic cards were identified

```
localhost% lspci | grep VGA
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v2/3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller (rev 09)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GF110 [GeForce GTX 570 Rev. 2] (rev a1)
```

But the OnBoard intel does not work

When I boot the system, the monitor conected with the OnBoard card starts, so the initial log show on that screen, but when the GNOME desktop starts, the screen of my OnBoard card freezes on the console, and only my 2 monitors connected to my OffBoard Graphic Card were started. The OnBoard monitor isn't identified. What I need to do?

After doing some tests, I've got no success. If I declare 2 devices with Xinerama disabled, GNOME starts in the onboard (intel) graphic card, after I login, my 2 monitors plugged on the offboard (nvidia) graphic card open the desktop, but the onboard monitor freezes on the login screen. If I enable the Xinerama option, when I login the onboard and offboard monitors become black, and I have no access to the OS, even trying ctrl+alt+f2 to open another terminal. What cant I do to enable the intel monitor? It isn't identifyed when I try xranr -q.

Comment: To debug: Look at the logs, `/var/log/Xorg.<n>.log` on my machine, where *n* is the screen number. The logs will tell you what happened. You are also setting up three different "displays" (screens) for the X server, so you'll need to tell each program in advance which screen to use, and each program will always stay on this screen. This is maybe not what you want. Also, screen numbers should be consecutive, and I'd start with the internal card as first screen.

Comment: If you can't figure out the problem, reduce the config to just two `device` sections with `identifier` and `driver` (no `screen`), and see if that works. Then slowly add things from there and see what causes the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, and yes, I want to use the monitors as a extented desktop, but I never tried with 2 different graphic cards, it's possible to do this like on Windows?

Comment: Yes, it's possible to do this. The Nvidia card can output a single desktop on two monitors, and the Intel card will be combined into this desktop using Xinerama. This is the default if you just have two `device` sections as I suggested. Add more options to suit your needs.

Comment: One thing that I don't understand, is how xorg know what monitor it's supposed to use, for example, if I connect 2 monitors to my Graphic card, but I want to use only one of them, how can I tell xorg to use a specific monitor? because in the config files, I didn't see any configuration identifying my monitors.

Comment: I'd have to look up the details, but you use a combination of `monitor` and `screen` sections, where the monitor ids match the output names shown in `xrandr`, together with a `serverlayout` section. Google a bit for xorg.conf examples.

Comment: Well, after doing some tests, I've got no success. If I declare 2 devices with Xinerama disabled, GNOME starts in the onboard (intel) graphic card, after I login, my 2 monitors plugged on the offboard (nvidia) graphic card open the desktop, but the onboard monitor freezes on the login screen. If I enable the Xinerama option, when I login the onboard and offboard monitors become black, and I have no access to the OS, even trying ctrl+alt+f2 to open another terminal. What cant I do to enable the intel monitor? It isn't identifyed when I try xranr -q.

Comment: many mainboards will disable the integrated graphics card if they detect an external VGA card available and there's no way to use both cards in that case

Comment: Even if I enabled the option on BIOS?